# Mysql select - improve performances

Tags: mysql, performance, between

I am working on an e-shop which sells products only via loans. I display 10 products per page in any category, each product has 3 different price tags - 3 different loan types. Everything went pretty well during testing time, query execution time was perfect, but today when transfered the changes to the production server, the site "collapsed" in about 2 minutes. The query that is used to select loan types sometimes hangs for ~10 seconds and it happens frequently and thus it cant keep up and its **hella slow**. The table that is used to store the data has approximately 2 milion records and each select looks like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM products_loans 
WHERE KOD IN("X17/Q30-10", "X17/12", "X17/5-24") 
AND 369.27 BETWEEN CENA_OD AND CENA_DO;
```

3 loan types and the price that needs to be in range between CENA_OD and CENA_DO, thus 3 rows are returned.

But since I need to display 10 products per page, I need to run it trough a modified select using **OR**, since I didnt find any other solution to this. I have asked about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912684/mysql-multiple-values-and-between), but got no answer. As mentioned in the referencing post, this has to be done separately since there is **no** column that could be used in a join (except of course price and code, but that ended very, very badly). Here is the `show create table`, kod and CENA_OD/CENA_DO very indexed via INDEX.

```
CREATE TABLE `products_loans` (
  `KOEF_ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `KOD` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `AKONTACIA` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `POCET_SPLATOK` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `koeficient` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL default '0.00',
  `CENA_OD` decimal(10,2) default NULL,
  `CENA_DO` decimal(10,2) default NULL,
  `PREDAJNA_CENA` decimal(10,2) default NULL,
  `AKONTACIA_SUMA` decimal(10,2) default NULL,
  `TYP_VYHODY` varchar(4) default NULL,
  `stage` smallint(6) NOT NULL default '1',
 PRIMARY KEY  (`KOEF_ID`),
 KEY `CENA_OD` (`CENA_OD`),
 KEY `CENA_DO` (`CENA_DO`),
 KEY `KOD` (`KOD`),
 KEY `stage` (`stage`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

And also selecting all loan types and later filtering them trough php doesnt work good, since each type has over 50k records and the select takes too much time as well...

Any ides about improving the speed are appreciated.

Edit:

Here is the explain

```
+----+-------------+----------------+-------+---------------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table          | type  | possible_keys       | key  | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra       |
+----+-------------+----------------+-------+---------------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | products_loans | range | CENA_OD,CENA_DO,KOD | KOD  | 92      | NULL | 190158 | Using where |
+----+-------------+----------------+-------+---------------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
```

I have tried the combined index and it improved the performance on the test server from 0.44 sec to 0.06 sec, I cant access the production server from home though, so I will have to try it tomorrow.

Comment: It's not the root of your problem, but using DECIMAL can cost you a little performance. Once you've got the major problem solved, if you still need more speed, consider using integers (BIGINT if necessary, especially if you're on a 64-bit server) and handling the decimal place in the application code.

Comment: How many different valued of KOD are there and how many different values of CENA_OD and CENA_DO? Can you post the output of `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` for your query?

Comment: How do your test and production server differ? Why the huge difference in speed? Are there many more concurrent users? More data? Different server version? Other?

Comment: The test server is the exact copy of the production one. The only difference is in users, test has only 1-5 users looking at the site at once, while the production one have around 100 maybe more concurrent users per e-shop (there are 3), but only one of them is using this table. And since the production server is owned by the company that we work for, they have their own databases, services, etc. running, but as far I know it doesnt interfere with the performance much, if at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to refactor your query like:

```
SELECT * FROM products_loans 
WHERE KOD IN("X17/Q30-10", "X17/12", "X17/5-24") 
AND CENA_OD >= 369.27
AND CENA_DO <= 369.27;
```

(mysql is not very smart when choosing indexes) and check the performance.

The next try is to add a combined key - (KOD,CENA_OD,CENA_DO)

And the next major try is to refactor your base to have products separated from prices. This should really help.

PS: you can also migrate to postgresql, it's smarter than mysql when choosing right indexes.

Comment: I would try this first. Indexes may not even be used if you have a constant on the left hand side of an expression.
Not sure on MySql, and it probably doesn't make a difference for the DB, but can you also LIMIT (FETCH FIRST?) the rows returned. This would save you the PHP processing and the IO of sending the results from DB to PHP.

Comment: Yes that would work with the select that takes one product from db, but if I need to take 10 (see referencing post) woudlnt that be the same (as for performance)?

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is that you are searching for intervals which contain a point (rather than the more normal query of all points in an interval). These queries do not work well with the standard B-tree index, so instead you need to use an R-Tree index. Unfortunately MySQL doesn't allow you to select an R-Tree index on a column, but you can get the desired index by changing your column type to GEOMETRY and using the geometric functions to check if the interval contains the point.

See [Quassnoi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/55159/quassnoi)'s article [Adjacency list vs. nested sets: MySQL](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/29/adjacency-list-vs-nested-sets-mysql/) where he explains this in more detail. The use case is different, but the techniques involved are the same. Here's an extract from the relevant part of the article:

> There is also a certain class of tasks that require searching for all ranges containing a known value:
>
> - Searching for an IP address in the IP range ban list
> - Searching for a given date within a date range
>
> and several others. These tasks can be improved by using R-Tree capabilities of MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL can only use 1 key. If you always get the entry by the 3 columns, depending on the actual data (range) in the columns one of the following could very well add a serious amount of performance:

```
ALTER TABLE products_loans ADD INDEX(KOD, CENA_OD, CENA_DO);
ALTER TABLE products_loans ADD INDEX(CENA_OD, CENA_DO, KOD);
```

Notice that the order of the columns matter! If that doesn't improve performance, give us the `EXPLAIN` output of the query.